# NodeJs, if statements inside connection.query

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js

i am a c# guy trying to create a login page using in react, node and mysql. i have a doubt that can i write 'if statements inside connection.query'. Below is the code snippet i am using. When i am trying to run this script, i am getting proxy error.

```
app.post('/api/world', (req, res) => {
 try{
  console.log(req.body);
  uname = req.body.post;

  var DBuserCheck = "SELECT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM `loginschema`.credentials WHERE uname =" + '"' + uname + '"' + ")";
  var DBpwdCheck = "SELECT pwd FROM `loginschema`.credentials WHERE uname =" + '"' + uname + '"';

connection.query(DBuserCheck, function(err,data){
if(DBuserCheck){
  connection.query(DBpwdCheck, function(err, pdata){
    if(pdata == req.body.password){
      res.json({Successfully_loggedin});
    }
    (err)? res.send(err) : res.json({pwdData_Wrong_Password: pdata});
    console.log('enter valid credentials');        
  });
}
(err) ? res.send(err) : res.json({ USERdata: data });
console.log('user query data: dataSTR',+data +" ; req string "+ req.body.post +"; uname string "+ uname);

 });
}
catch(ex){
  console.log('Message from Catch is ----->>>> '+ex);
}

});
```

Is my code correct or i have to follow any other procedure. My code first runs correctly and crashes at the ending. I am getting the below error.

```
PS H:\PyProjects\login\loginproj> yarn dev
yarn run v1.17.3
$ concurrently --kill-others-on-fail "yarn server" "yarn client"
$ cd client && yarn start
$ nodemon server.js
$ react-scripts start
[0] [nodemon] 1.19.4
[0] [nodemon] to restart at any time, enter `rs`
[0] [nodemon] watching dir(s): *.*
[0] [nodemon] watching extensions: js,mjs,json
[0] [nodemon] starting `node server.js`
[0] Listening on port 5000
[1] Browserslist: caniuse-lite is outdated. Please run next command `yarn upgrade caniuse-lite browserslist`
[1] Starting the development server...
[1]
[1] Browserslist: caniuse-lite is outdated. Please run next command `yarn upgrade`
[1] Browserslist: caniuse-lite is outdated. Please run next command `yarn upgrade`
[1] Compiled successfully!
[1]
[1] You can now view create-react-app-express in the browser.
[1]
[1]   Local:            http://localhost:3000/
[1]   On Your Network:  http://10.0.0.65:3000/
[1]
[1] Note that the development build is not optimized.
[1] To create a production build, use yarn build.
[1]
[0] {}
[0] user query data: dataSTR NaN ; req string undefined; uname string undefined
[0] H:\PyProjects\login\loginproj\node_modules\mysql\lib\protocol\Parser.js:437
[0]       throw err; // Rethrow non-MySQL errors
[0]       ^
[0]
[0] Error [ERR_HTTP_HEADERS_SENT]: Cannot set headers after they are sent to the client
[0]     at ServerResponse.setHeader (_http_outgoing.js:470:11)
[0]     at ServerResponse.header (H:\PyProjects\login\loginproj\node_modules\express\lib\response.js:771:10)
[0]     at ServerResponse.send (H:\PyProjects\login\loginproj\node_modules\express\lib\response.js:170:12)
[0]     at ServerResponse.json (H:\PyProjects\login\loginproj\node_modules\express\lib\response.js:267:15)
[0]     at Query.<anonymous> (H:\PyProjects\login\loginproj\server.js:44:36)
[0]     at Query.<anonymous> (H:\PyProjects\login\loginproj\node_modules\mysql\lib\Connection.js:525:10)
[0]     at Query._callback (H:\PyProjects\login\loginproj\node_modules\mysql\lib\Connection.js:491:16)
        at Query.Sequence.end (H:\PyProjects\login\loginproj\node_modules\mysql\lib\protocol\sequences\Sequence.js:83:24)
[0]     at Query._handleFinalResultPacket (H:\PyProjects\login\loginproj\node_modules\mysql\lib\protocol\sequences\Query.js:139:8)
[0]     at Query.EofPacket (H:\PyProjects\login\loginproj\node_modules\mysql\lib\protocol\sequences\Query.js:123:8)
[0] [nodemon] app crashed - waiting for file changes before starting...
[1] Proxy error: Could not proxy request /api/world from localhost:3000 to http://localhost:5000/.
[1] See https://nodejs.org/api/errors.html#errors_common_system_errors for more information (ECONNREFUSED).
```

Comment: The `if` condition is inside the callback function of `connection.query` which is fine.
Proxy error means an issue with connection. Could you add the exact error you are getting ?

Comment: add try-catch block and post with error message

Comment: Error message:    Proxy error: Could not proxy request /api/world from localhost:3000 to http://localhost:5000/.
See https://nodejs.org/api/errors.html#errors_common_system_errors for more information (ECONNREFUSED).

Comment: if i execute the same thing with only one database query, i am able to make interaction between client and server. when i am adding the second query, getting this problem(above error message)

Comment: here is the link for single query execution. ---> https://drive.google.com/open?id=17d0-7zpZoAZA7_elAPHaHlmSOEb-gcfk

Comment: @Jayakumar Thangavel I have updated my question by adding try catch method to code and added total error message.

Comment: Most important point to say here. Do never ever use this code in production outside an internal network. Never put directly data send to server this why in a database query!!! Use Validation & prepared statements!

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion @elsololobo . This project is just for my knowledge

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Accoding to your error from your code send response multiple times, so here is your working code

```
app.post('/api/world', (req, res) => {
    try {
        console.log(req.body);
        uname = req.body.post;

        var DBuserCheck = "SELECT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM `loginschema`.credentials WHERE uname =" + '"' + uname + '"' + ")";
        var DBpwdCheck = "SELECT pwd FROM `loginschema`.credentials WHERE uname =" + '"' + uname + '"';

        connection.query(DBuserCheck, function (err, data) {
            if(err) {
                res.send(err) : res.json({ USERdata: data })
                console.log('user query data: dataSTR', +data + " ; req string " + req.body.post + "; uname string " + uname);
            } else {
                connection.query(DBpwdCheck, function (err, pdata) {
                    if (pdata == req.body.password) {
                        res.json({ Successfully_loggedin });

                    } else {
                        (err) ? res.send(err) : res.json({ pwdData_Wrong_Password: pdata });
                        console.log('enter valid credentials');
                    }
                });
            }
        });
    }
    catch (ex) {
        console.log('Message from Catch is ----->>>> ' + ex);
    }

});
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply. I had executed with this code. running good. but even though i am giving the right password, the password is not validating. can you please help me.

Comment: can you please try to look into pdata variable maybe your database password inside pdata.pwd somthing like

Comment: or just share result of pdata, so i can figure out by myself

Comment: i tried printing pdata variable, i am getting undefined.

Comment: Than first you have to check your query, maybe there are some issue in your query

Answer (score 0):

This solved my issue. I added if statement like this .

```
if(loginUserId ===stat.userId && singlePost.id){
  return Object.assign({}, {
    stat_id: stat.id,
    is_status : true,
  })
} else if(loginUserId ===userId){
  return Object.assign({}, {
    stat_id: stat.id,
    is_status : true,
  })
}  else {
  return Object.assign({}, {
    stat_id: stat.id,
    is_status : false,
  })
}
```